# How do I import google earth plug-in map into google earth desktop?

Tags: google-earth, google-earth-plugin

I want to the map off of [this](http://www.oilandgasinfrastructure.com/home/oilandgasnorthamerica/canada) website:
Specifically [this](http://pd59o3se67jphso7ckbcc1fjecp9593u-a-sites-opensocial.googleusercontent.com/gadgets/ifr?url=http://dl.google.com/developers/maps/embedkmlgadget.xml&container=enterprise&view=default&lang=en&country=GB&sanitize=0&v=4c99e2abaa86f93f&libs=core&mid=197&parent=http://www.oilandgasinfrastructure.com/home/oilandgasnorthamerica/canada#up_earth_show_buildings=false&up_earth_show_roads=false&up_kml_url=https://sites.google.com/site/oilandgasinfrastructure/canada.kmz?attredirects%3D0%26d%3D1&up_earth_sphere=earth&up_maps_default_type=map&up_maps_zoom_out=false&up_earth_fly_from_space=false&up_earth_2d_fallback=false&up_earth_show_borders=false&up_earth_show_terrain=true&up_view_mode=earth&up_earth_show_nav_controls=true&st=e%3DAIHE3cDJCrq1F%252FTV5bg%252FDGMg1KtpgFVGRkGAyWprPFl9TRGW%252FMPby1V%252FQPUWcl%252FEPL%252F7g2wJnCkMdMT65K0vl48et4U0LllMS%252Fk4bwm0VsoVMWXV2IPnOXghVQOi265OrTrV6Q1hYe4J%26c%3Denterprise&rpctoken=-6371760590239800560) map:

To be imported in Google Earth Desktop where I can do further analysis.

Is there someway of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most cases you would have to comb through the javaScript code for some clues but in this case it's easy.

If you view-source on the HTML page then you'll see the target KML file:

```
...up_kml_url=https://sites.google.com/site/oilandgasinfrastructure/canada.kmz...
```

If you enter the URL into a web browser then it will download and launch the target KMZ file into Google Earth desktop for further analysis.

URL: https://sites.google.com/site/oilandgasinfrastructure/canada.kmz